# How to configure Maven for a Nuget repository

Tags: java, maven, nuget

I'm looking to see anyone knows if Maven can be configured to point to a Nuget repository so that a dependency can put items from Nuget?

Comment: What are you planning to do? Is this a Java program you are trying to build or something else?

Comment: well it really doesn't matter. I just need to know if Maven can be configured to pull from a Nuget repository like a Maven repository. I know I can setup multiple Maven repos if the artifacts I need are in different locations, but, in this particular case what I need is in a Nuget repo.

Comment: No, it cannot. What is the background?

Comment: I have a Java application and when my assembly builds the deployable artifact, I now need to grab and include something that's in a Nuget repo. It's easy to grab dependencies from a Maven repo and include them when I build the deployable artifact, however this particular dependency is in Nuget. So if there is no way for Maven to pull from a Nuget repo then I'll need to come up with a different strategy.